# Assets Precompile Capistrano 3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

I am a newbie in deploying,

Using capistrano 3.4 for deploying

I am trying to deploy for staging environment, using this task for precompile

```
desc "assets precompile"
  task :precompile do
    on roles(:rails) do
      execute "cd #{release_path} && bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} "
    end
  end
  after :publishing, :precompile
```

But precompile is getting freeze not moving, if i uncomment these above task and deploy then it gets deployed but assets are not loading.

Please help how to proceed

Answer (score 3):

No need to write manual task for asset precomplie.There is nice gem available for it.

Include `gem 'capistrano-rails'` in Gemfile.

and add `require 'capistrano/rails/assets`' in capfile.

Thanks..!!